# how to insert concate value using trigger when new row inserted in mysql

Tags: mysql

In my schema I had two columns ,I am new to MySQL how to concatenate columns using Computed Column in mysql

```
ordertbl schema

Autoorderid int  auto-increment
Orderid         varchar(45)
```

I want to value orderid value insert when new row inserted

i had created the trigger for but this trigger is not firing when i am inserting the row

```
insert into order_master(customerID,ItemID,quantity,Unitprice,Total)  values ('07961A','1000',6,5,30)

use ntc_sales; DELIMITER
$$ CREATE TRIGGER order_master_BINS BEFORE INSERT ON order_master FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.OrderID = CONCAT('ORD' ,NEW.AutoOrderID) ; end;
```

create table
    enter code here

```
     CREATE TABLE Demo(ID INT   PRIMARY KEY,
     IDwithChar AS 'ORD' + RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)), 6) PERSISTED,valuevar nvarchar(45)
                 )
```

This is showing syntax error in mysql how to create table as above schema  in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do this using a trigger in MySQL.

- A `BEFORE` trigger is run before the auto increment value is set, so `NEW.AutoOrderID` will always be 0.
- An `AFTER` trigger cannot update the same table as it is triggered on.

In other words, instead of triggering on an INSERT, creating the row using a stored procedure that does the insert/update in a single transaction is probably the best way to proceed.

EDIT: You could use a separate table for the sequence, but that would not guarantee that the order number is the same value as AutoOrderID, just a unique value.

```
CREATE TABLE order_sequence (
  seq INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);

CREATE TRIGGER order_master_BINS BEFORE INSERT ON order_master 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO order_sequence VALUES (0);
  SET NEW.OrderID = CONCAT('ORD', LAST_INSERT_ID());
END
```

[An SQLfiddle to test the alternate solution with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d3d2/1).

Comment: cant we use Computed Column in mysql? if yes how? for my result to  concate value

Comment: @user1983379 As far as I know, there is no way to do exactly what you're trying to do. The only obvious way to do computed fields in MySQL is using triggers, and when you do, you're limited to what triggers support. You may be able to create a similar solution using a separate table to generate the sequence.

Comment: hi @Joachim Isaksson here this CREATE TABLE dbo.Demo(ID INT Identity  PRIMARY KEY,
                      IDwithChar AS 'C' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)), 6) PERSISTED
                     ) is working sql how to write  in mysql?

Comment: @user1983379 There is no way to declare computed fields in MySQL the way it is in SQL Server.

Comment: ok u had give me one sugggestion "You may be able to create a similar solution using a separate table to generate the sequence" i didnt understood can u please explain me this?

Comment: @user1983379 Added a possible solution to the answer.

Comment: please check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2df60  here i am getting error

Comment: @user1983379 I'm not sure what error you're referring to. [This fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a3d6/1) seems to work well.